# A submodel of set theory with all reals which every set is analytic

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory

This is a continuation of [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412137/a-baire-subset-of-reals-that-is-not-suslin-measurable). Recall that a subset $A \subseteq {}^\omega\omega$ is *analytic* if it is the continuous image of the Baire space. I would like to know if there exist two models $N \subseteq M$ such that:

1. $M \models \mathsf{ZFC}$ (or just $M \models \mathsf{ZF} + \text{There exists a non-principal ultrafilter}$).
2. $N \models \mathsf{ZF} + \text{Every subset of reals is analytic}$.
3. $({}^\omega\omega)^M = ({}^\omega\omega)^N$.

From the comments of previous posts, it's worth noting that:

1. Under $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC}$, one can construct the universal analytic set and prove that it is not analytic. Thus, $N \not\models \mathsf{DC}$.
2. A (somewhat trivial) example of a model in which every subset of reals is analytic is the Feferman-Levy model, where the reals is a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: Maybe I'm having a silly moment but I don't think "Every set is analytic" is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ in the first place. We don't need choice to get a surjection $h$ from Baire space to the set of continuous maps on Baire space; now consider the set $\{x: x\not\in h(x)\}$. (Re: Feferman-Levy, note that in that model $\mathbb{R}$ isn't a countable union of "uniformly countable" sets, and without uniform countability I don't see why in FL every set should be analytic. But maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber what is "uniformly countable"?

Comment: Without choice, for a family of sets $\mathscr{A}=(A_i)_{i\in I}$ the statements "Each $A_i\in\mathscr{A}$ is countable" and "There is a function assigning each $A_i$ to a surjection $\omega\rightarrow A_i$" are not automatically equivalent; the latter is what I mean by uniform countability. In the Feferman-Levy model $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, but no model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ can have $\mathbb{R}$ be a countable union of *uniformly* countable sets. [This old MSE answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3638572/28111) may be relevant.

Comment: I see, but I'm not sure why the following alternative approach fails: I believe its a theorem of $\mathsf{ZF}$ that every analytic set can be seen as the Suslin operation applied to a Suslin scheme of closed sets (see my linked question, but my Suslin operation is different). I also believe that one can see from the operation that this implies countable union of countable set is analytic (as singletons are closed). Therefore, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is analytic.

Comment: "I also believe that one can see from the operation that this implies countable union of countable set is analytic" That looks dubious to me (in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone anyways); I'd try to prove it in detail.

Comment: I see, it might just be uniform countability that makes a proof not possible. My attempted proof is as follows: Suppose $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{i \in \omega} A_i$ where each $A_i$ is countable. Fix $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Let $h_i : \omega \to A_i$ be a bijection. Define the Suslin scheme $\left\langle X_s : s \in {}^{<\omega}\omega\right\rangle$ by stipulating that $X_s = X \cap \{h_i(n)\}$ if $s = (i,n)$, and $X_s = \emptyset$ otherwise (defining this Suslin scheme seems to require uniform countability). Then $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{X}) = \bigcup_{i \in \omega} X \cap A_i = X$.

Comment: Note that my Suslin operation $\mathcal{A}$ here refers to:
$$
\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{X}) = \bigcup_{a \in {}^\omega\omega}\bigcap_{n \in \omega} X_{a \upharpoonright n}.
$$

Comment: You can't say "Let $h_i:\omega\rightarrow A_i$ be a bijection" unless the $A_i$s are uniformly countable. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ this isn't an issue, but in $\mathsf{ZF}$ it's crucial.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand. Thank you for your hel!

Comment: Glad to help! (I presume that's a typo, but I approve. :P)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, the principle "Every set is analytic" is not consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ in the first place. We don't need choice to get a surjection $h$ from Baire space to the set of continuous maps on Baire space. But once we have such an $h$, the "diagonalizing" set $\{x: x\not\in h(x)\}$ can't be analytic.

---

Let me show how to get such an $h$ in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone. Working in $\mathsf{ZF}$, let $C$ be the set of continuous maps $\omega^\omega\rightarrow\omega^\omega$. To each $\gamma\in C$ we assign the set $$S(\gamma)=\{(\sigma,\tau)\in\omega^{<\omega}\times\omega^{<\omega}: \forall f\succ \sigma(\gamma(f)\succ\tau)\}.$$ By your favorite coding mechanism we can identify $S(\gamma)$ with some $\hat{S}(\gamma)\in\omega^\omega$. But $\hat{S}(\gamma)=\hat{S}(\gamma')$ implies $\gamma=\gamma'$ for continuous $\gamma,\gamma'$, so in fact $\hat{S}$ gives an injection from $C$ to $\omega^\omega$.

Now turning a surjection into an injection without choice is hard, but the converse is trivial: for $x\in\omega^\omega$, let $h(r)=\hat{S}^{-1}(r)$ if $r\in ran(\hat{S})$, and let $h(r)$ be the always-zero map otherwise.